# Image recognition and Uniqueness detection

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am new to AI/ML and am trying to use the same for solving the following problem.
I have a set of (custom) images which while having common characteristics also will have a unique pattern/signature and color value. What set of algorithms should I use to have the pass in following manner:
1. Recognize the common characteristic (like presence of a triangle at any position in a 10x10mm image). If present, proceed, else exit.
2. Identify the unique pattern/signature to identify each image individually. The pattern/signature could be shape (visible to human eye or hidden like using an overlay shape using background image with no boundaries).
3. Store color tone/hue/saturation to determine any loss/difference (maybe because the capture source is different from the original one).

While this is in way similar to face recognition algo, for me saturation/shadow will matter while being direction independent.

I figure that using CNN may be the way to go for step#2 and SVN for step#1, any input on training, specifics will be appreciated. What about step#3, use BGR2HSV? The objective is to use ML/AI and not get into machine-vision.

Comment: But why `objective is to use ML/AI and not get into machine-vision.` ?

Comment: Since the patterns will be random, which will be programmatically difficult to achieve from a precision standpoint.

Comment: Honestly machine-vision (erm, computer-vision) is basically glorified CNNs.

Comment: @Coldspeed So you are suggesting that I stay with CNN. Would it be a overkill for any step outlined above as against using SVN?

Comment: @KoushikB. I think you mean SVM. And no, I don't believe it is overkill in the least. CNNs outclass SVMs in image based ML problems.

Comment: @Coldspeed Appreciate your response. Any recommendation on how to train the model for a specific feature/shape anywhere in the image to satisfy step#1?

Comment: @KoushikB. What I have to say is a little long for a comment, so I shall write an answer.

Comment: @Coldspeed Will appreciate. Really looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Recognize the common characteristic (like presence of a triangle at any position in a 10x10mm image). If present, proceed, else exit.

In a sense, what you want is a classifier that can detect patterns in an image. However, we can train classifiers to detect *certain types of patterns* in images.

For example, I can train a classifier to recognise squares and circles, but if I show it an image with a triangle in it, I cannot expect it to tell me it is a triangle, because it has never seen it before. The downside is, your classifier will end up misclassifying it as one of the shapes it *knows* to exist: either square or circle. The upside is, you can prevent this.

> 2. Identify the unique pattern/signature to identify each image individually.

What you want to do is train a classifier on a **large** amount of labelled data. If you want the classifier to detect squares, circles, or triangles in an image, you must train it with a large amount of labelled images of squares, circles and triangles.

> 3. Store color tone/hue/saturation to determine any loss/difference (maybe because the capture source is different from the original one).

Now, you are leaving the territory of simple image labelling and entering the world of computer vision. This is not as simple as a vanilla image classifier, but it is possible and there are a lot of online tools to help you do this. For example, you may take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org). They have an implementation in python and C++.

> I figure that using CNN may be the way to go for step#2 and SVN for
>   step#1

You can combine step 1 and step 2 with a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN). You do not need to use a two step prediction process. However, beware, if you pass the CNN an image of a car, it will still label it as a shape. You can, again circumvent this by training it on a million positive samples of shapes, and a million negative samples of random other images with the class "Other". This way, anything that is not a shape will get classified into "Other". This is one possibility.

> What about step#3, use BGR2HSV? The objective is to use ML/AI and not
>   get into machine-vision.

With the inclusion of this step, there is no option but to get into computer vision. I am not exactly sure how to go about this, but I can guarantee OpenCV will provide you a way to do this. In fact, with OpenCV, you will no longer need to implement your own CNN, because OpenCV has its own image labelling libraries.

Comment: Thank. Was not aware that OpenCV has its own image labeling libraries.<br> Regarding step#2, the idea is to find uniqueness, something similar to identify each face differently once we know it is a face. The only downside to that I am trying to accomplish is that I can't train it with many sample, rather one sample only. Does this mean it is beyond the scope of ML and enters the world of Computer Vision?

Comment: @KoushikB. Yes. It is a self contained computer vision framework.

Comment: I have switched entirely to OpenCV (first on Java and now completely in C++) for all processing. Your answer did help in formulating the direction.